How can repair problem using Clonezilla to create disk image
I used Clonezilla to make a disk image. I has picked the source and destination drives. Disk #1 is a 2 Tb drive with about 53 Mb in use. Disk #2 is a Maxtor 300 +/-. I started the process.
Here is what the screen says.
Chking the disk space No space on the device hence the data can not be written to /home/partial The saved image file dddd..zst is incomplete.You have to increase disk space then start clonez start mode again.

I last used Clonezilla 4 yrs.ago with flawless results.

How is the Maxtor formatted? Is it FAT32?

@Organic Marble.I am not sure, either of these: ext 3 or ext4.

OK. That message comes up if the destination partition is FAT32.  So there must be some other things that cause it.

@Organic Marble I hope both hard drives are not bricked " I have no other backups.

I did a Ctrl+Alt+Delete and it booted right up.
